# Android BiometricPrompt shows Iris scanner on Samsung running Android Pie

Tags: android, prompt

I'm trying to authenticate user in my application using the [BiometricPrompt](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/biometrics/BiometricPrompt). Now on some devices like Samsung Galaxy S8 running Android Pie, if i go to settings and change prefered biometric to Irises, the BiometricPrompt.authenticate method shows the Iris scanner instead of fingerprint. Is there any way to always prompt fingerprint scanner?[image]

Comment: `Is there any way to always prompt fingerprint scanner?` Can you explain your motivation?

Comment: well, some of the customers do not think face/iris recognition is a reliable authorization method and they want to use the fingerprint sensor only.

Comment: Those customers probably wouldn't go into settings and set iris scanning as their preferred method of biometric authentication, would they?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not supported today. I [filed an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111315641) regarding this last summer, but I haven't really received any meaningful response yet.

Comment: @Michael yeah also google disabled the comment section.

Comment: @Michael now in android 11 we can set the allowed authenticators. we can choose between BIOMETRIC_STRONG, BIOMETRIC_WEAK and DEVICE_CREDENTIAL. For more information: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/hardware/biometrics/BiometricPrompt.Builder#setallowedauthenticators